# Unable to access jarfile XYZ.jar

Tags: python, oop, jar, pycharm

I had a java application which was testing servers. We are migrating to python, and for a start we are making use of the jar from the java application.

I use the jar in my python script, and call the

```
subprocess.call(
    ['java', '-jar', 'XYZ.jar', '-url', 'opc.tcp://localhost:XXXX', '-check', 'AB', '-specVersion', '2.0', '-test', 'testclient.TestGeneral'])
```

This works perfect!
However, we plan to have a clear structure by using classes(OOP).

So I make some modifications and I write the below

```
class TestClient:

    def performTest(self):

        subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'XYZ.jar', '-url', 'opc.tcp://localhost:XXXX', '-check', 'AB', '-specVersion', '2.0', '-test', 'testclient.TestGeneral'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = TestClient()
    client.performTest()
```

I get an error saying

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile XYZ.jar
```

How is it that the jar becomes unaccesable? Am i missing something here? Please let me know

Comment: where is the jar placed? Is it in the same directory. try using `./XYZ.jar` pre-pending `./`

Comment: Hi @ShaileshSuryawanshi, I fixed it, as I had not added the working directory path to the newly created run configuration. Thank you anyway